# Calculating Recency . Frequency and Monetary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am doing RFM (recency,f requency, monetary) analysis data in Python. The last invoice date of purchase of my dataset is 2022-12-30.

Dataset looks like this:

| custname | invdate | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 17/01/2022 | 517 |
| ghi | 12/30/2022 | 15,111,111 |

From the dataset, I first calculated the last purchase date:

code: `df['invdate'].max()`

output: `Timestamp('2022-12-30 00:00:00')`

Then I calculated the recency:

First step: I noted the last invoice date, and set that date as "now"

```
now=dt.date(2022,12,30)
print(now)
```

output for now: `2022-12-30`

Second step: The final recency code:

```
recency_df['Recency'] = recency_df['invdate'].apply(lambda x: (now - x).days)
```

but the result seems wrong:

| custname | invdate | revenue | recency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 17/01/2022 | 517 | 347 |
| ghi | 12/30/2022 | 15,111,111 | 0 |

If the customer "ghi" bought on December 30,2022 with maximum revenue, shouldn't its recency be the highest? Have I used a wrong recency calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the incorrect recency calculation for customer "ghi" is because the date format in the dataset is in the format of month/day/year (MM/DD/YYYY) instead of day/month/year (DD/MM/YYYY). As a result, the code you used to calculate the recency is subtracting the invoice date from the current date in an incorrect way.

To fix this, you should convert the date column into a datetime format using pandas' to_datetime function with the format argument set to "%m/%d/%Y". This will ensure that the date is interpreted correctly as month/day/year.

```
# convert date column to datetime format
df['invdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['invdate'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

# calculate recency
now = dt.date(2022,12,30)
df['Recency'] = (now - df['invdate']).dt.days
```